# jQuerymobile, how to fire a callback after an ajax page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't figure out how to fire a callback after a specific page load.

For instance, I have two pages:

```
<!-- my page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

    <a href="#bar">bar</a></p>  

</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- other page  -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

    <div id="slideshow"></div>

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Pretty easy right? Now I want to fire that slideshow as a callback, but only when "bar" page is ready. Binding to pagecreate event on documents fires on every pagecreate,

```
 $(document).bind('pagecreate') // I don't need this for every page, just my slideshows
```

and

```
$( '#bar' ).on( 'pagecreate',function(event){ 
    whatEver();     // why you don't just work? :/
});
```

does not work at all (or I just didn't figure out what it is supposed to do).

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#bar',function(event){ 
    whatEver();     // why you don't just work? :/
});
```

But if you are doing anything visual on this page (like slideshow) I would advise using:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#bar',function(event){ 
    whatEver();     // why you don't just work? :/
});
```

jQM has a problem with displaying visual changes (like slideshow plugins, carousels etc..) in every page event except **pageshow**. **Pageshow** is the last event to load, in that case page is fully loaded and page has a proper height.

Comment: no way, even passing the id as argument it fires at every pagecreate or at every pageshow. :/

Comment: My example should not fire in every page. Take a look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8hKe2/ , and modify your code in regards to it.

Comment: you are right, even in my fiddle works fine, should have a problem in my code. Anyway thank you, it is a good and clear answer. // http://jsfiddle.net/5Y4jf/6/